# Cannot read property 'name' of null error

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm still a baby on web development. I am getting the following error, can
anyone help me?

Schema:

```
var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   image: String,
   description: String,
   _id: String
});
var Campground = mongoose.model("Campground", campgroundSchema);
app.get("/campgrounds/:id",function(req , res){
Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundCampgrounds){
                  if(err){
                          console.log(err);
                         }else{
                       res.render("show", {campground: foundCampgrounds});
                     }
                 });
            });
```

This is the index.ejs template:

```
    <div class="row text-center" style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap">
        <% campgrounds.forEach(function(campground){ %>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6"> 
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="<%= campground.image %>">
                        <div class="caption">
                             <h4> <%= campground.name %> </h4>
                         </div>
                         <p><a href="/campgrounds/ <%= campground._id %>" 
                           class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
                         </p>
                 </div>
             </div>
         <% }) %>
    </div>
```

show.ejs:

```
<%- include('partials/header')%> 
    <h1>this is a show template</h1>
    <p><%= campground.name %></p>
<%- include('partials/footer')%>
```

TypeError:

```
 Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

Comment: Can you add the nodejs-code where you `res.render(..)` the page?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question?

Comment: You have to check if foundCampgrounds exists.
Mongoose `findById` return `undefined` if it cannot find your record.

You can use:
`if (foundCampgrounds) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You should check if `campground` is defined at all - you can either do that in your nodejs-controller or in your template. Here's an example for `ejs`:

```
<%- include('partials/header')%>
    <% if (campground) { %> 
      <h1>this is a show template</h1>
      <p><%= campground.name %></p>
    <% } else { %> 
      <h1>No camground data was found</h1> 
   <% } %>
<%- include('partials/footer')%>
```

Comment: The error is no longer there. I'm now getting: No campground data was found. The else part of your suggestion. But this cannot be true since I have one campground available on the database. Any further suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure that there's a record with `_id` set to the `id`-param in your url?

Comment: Not sure if I follow you....can you elaborate further?

Comment: Well, your mongodb records have a `_id` field. Since you are using `app.get("/campgrounds/:id")` (`:id` will be set to `req.params.id`) the question is if there is a record with this id? If not, obviously no record will be returned.

Comment: Are you referring to this?                                                            
db.campgrounds.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5efed7d4ac396d054f8b8693"), "name" : "Granite Hill", "image" : "https://images.pexels.com/photos/45241/tent-camp-night
-star-45241.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350", "description" : "This is a huge granite hill, no bathrooms. No water. Beautiful granite
!", "__v" : 0 }

Comment: Yes, in order for your code to work (i.e. `Campground.findById` in particular) your request-url must contain `/campgrounds/5efed7d4ac396d054f8b8693` to get the record you mentioned.

Comment: I included your suggestion but still no improvement.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Would appreciate if you accepted my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On the index.ejs. Use a span to retrieve the _id from the
DB, as follows

```
        <span> <%= campground._id %> </span>
```

Why? Because _id is a unique object and is auto-generated. No need to even
include it on the Schema unless you want to create it yourself on which case
you'll then amend the controller with a variable. I struggled with this but now
okay.